Kamal is trying to run a IRB command on deploy
I have a trouble since i have been trying to deploy an application with kamal 2 and Rails 8.
If i run docker-compose up on development environment, my application runs fine and without any trouble.
But when i try to run dotenv kamal deploy or dotenv kamal setup he do a lot of steps to make the new image to the docker on the droplet (on DigitalOcean), and when he is almost finishing, he tries to run the container, and the container returns the error message:
Switch to inspect mode.
if i run docker ps -a i get the information about that container, and the command he tries to run, for some reason, he have try to run IRB instead bin/rails s



CONTAINER_ID
IMAGE
COMMAND
CREATED
STATUS




316cd0c2ce39
my_user/my_app:f87ed63df53887359dc65647081ca7c0de3f52d3
"irb"
About a minute ago
Exited (0) 34 seconds ago



Below is my Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml, i don't think that is a problem with them, but for information purposes:
docker-compose.yml
services:
  redis:
    image: "redis:7-alpine"
    ports:
      - 6379
    volumes:
    - ./tmp/redis_data:/var/lib/redis/data

  db:
    image: postgres:14
    container_name: myapp-postgres-14.2
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USERNAME: ${DB_USERNAME}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${DB_NAME}
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    expose:
      - "5432"

  web:
    build: .
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    entrypoint: config/setup_app.sh
    command: bash -c "bin/rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'"
    environment:
      REDIS_URL: ${REDIS_URL}
      POSTGRES_USERNAME: ${DB_USERNAME}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${DB_NAME}
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - .:/home/app/web
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis

volumes:
  postgres_data: {}
networks:
  default:
    name: myapp_default

Dockerfile:
FROM ruby:3.3.6

RUN apt update
RUN apt upgrade -y
RUN apt install lsb-base lsb-release -y

#Postgres
RUN sh -c 'echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt $(lsb_release -cs)-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list'
RUN wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | apt-key add -

RUN apt update \
  && apt install -y htop \
                    nano \
                    postgresql-14 \
                    build-essential libssl-dev zlib1g-dev libreadline-dev \
libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev \
libffi-dev software-properties-common

RUN curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_18.x | bash - && \
    apt-get install -y nodejs

RUN gem install pg

ADD . /home/app/web
WORKDIR /home/app/web

COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install

RUN bundle install --jobs 5 --retry 5

my entrypoint file, setup_app.sh
#! /bin/sh

set -e

bundle check || bundle install --jobs 5 --retry 5

if [ -f tmp/pids/server.pid ]; then
  rm tmp/pids/server.pid
fi

echo ' --> Running migrations'
rails db:migrate
echo ' --> End of migrations'


exec "$@" # command from docker-compose.yml

and my deploy.yml from kamal config.
# Name of your application. Used to uniquely configure containers.
service: myapp

# Name of the container image.
image: myuser/myapp

# Deploy to these servers.
servers:
  web:
    - 111.111.111.111
  # job:
  #   hosts:
  #     - 192.168.0.1
  #   cmd: bin/jobs

# Enable SSL auto certification via Let's Encrypt and allow for multiple apps on a single web server.
# Remove this section when using multiple web servers and ensure you terminate SSL at your load balancer.
#
# Note: If using Cloudflare, set encryption mode in SSL/TLS setting to "Full" to enable CF-to-app encryption. 
proxy: 
  ssl: false
  host: 111.111.111.111
  # Proxy connects to your container on port 80 by default.
  app_port: 3000

# Credentials for your image host.
registry:
  # Specify the registry server, if you're not using Docker Hub
  # server: registry.digitalocean.com / ghcr.io / ...
  username: myuser

  # Always use an access token rather than real password (pulled from .kamal/secrets).
  password:
    - KAMAL_REGISTRY_PASSWORD

# Configure builder setup.
builder:
  arch: amd64

# Inject ENV variables into containers (secrets come from .kamal/secrets).
#
# env:
#   clear:
#     DB_HOST: 192.168.0.2
#   secret:
#     - RAILS_MASTER_KEY

# Aliases are triggered with "bin/kamal <alias>". You can overwrite arguments on invocation:
# "bin/kamal logs -r job" will tail logs from the first server in the job section.
#
# aliases:
#   shell: app exec --interactive --reuse "bash"

# Use a different ssh user than root
#
ssh:
  user: myapp

# Use a persistent storage volume.
#
# volumes:
#   - "app_storage:/app/storage"

# Bridge fingerprinted assets, like JS and CSS, between versions to avoid
# hitting 404 on in-flight requests. Combines all files from new and old
# version inside the asset_path.
#
asset_path: /home/app/web/public

# Configure rolling deploys by setting a wait time between batches of restarts.
#
# boot:
#   limit: 10 # Can also specify as a percentage of total hosts, such as "25%"
#   wait: 2

# Use accessory services (secrets come from .kamal/secrets).
#
accessories:
  db:
    image: postgres:14
    host: 111.111.111.111
    port: 5432
    env:
      secret:
        - DB_USERNAME
        - DB_PASSWORD
        - DB_NAME
        - DB_HOST
    directories:
      - data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  redis:
    image: "redis:7-alpine"
    host: 111.111.111.111
    port: 6379
    directories:
    - data:/data


kamal deploy log:
dotenv kamal deploy
Log into image registry...
  INFO [dd913298] Running docker login -u [REDACTED] -p [REDACTED] as user@localhost
  INFO [dd913298] Finished in 1.348 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [6607e156] Running docker login -u [REDACTED] -p [REDACTED] on 111.111.111.111
  INFO [6607e156] Finished in 1.860 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
Build and push app image...
  INFO [0b3d60eb] Running docker --version && docker buildx version as user@localhost
  INFO [0b3d60eb] Finished in 0.052 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
Building from a local git clone, so ignoring these uncommitted changes:
 M Gemfile
 M Gemfile.lock
 M config/deploy.yml
 M docker-compose.yml
?? .kamal/secrets
  INFO Cloning repo into build directory `/tmp/kamal-clones/myapp-e1d4eb0ddcfac/myapp/`...
  INFO [ba42b9ff] Running /usr/bin/env git -C /tmp/kamal-clones/myapp-e1d4eb0ddcfac clone /home/user/myapp --recurse-submodules as user@localhost
  INFO Resetting local clone as `/tmp/kamal-clones/myapp-e1d4eb0ddcfac/myapp/` already exists...
  INFO [1fe157f2] Running /usr/bin/env git -C /tmp/kamal-clones/myapp-e1d4eb0ddcfac/myapp/ remote set-url origin /home/user/myapp as user@localhost
  INFO [1fe157f2] Finished in 0.002 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [a46e99ce] Running /usr/bin/env git -C /tmp/kamal-clones/myapp-e1d4eb0ddcfac/myapp/ fetch origin as user@localhost
  INFO [a46e99ce] Finished in 0.007 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [b2e50486] Running /usr/bin/env git -C /tmp/kamal-clones/myapp-e1d4eb0ddcfac/myapp/ reset --hard f87ed63df53887359dc65647081ca7c0de3f52d3 as user@localhost
  INFO [b2e50486] Finished in 0.003 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [7323847f] Running /usr/bin/env git -C /tmp/kamal-clones/myapp-e1d4eb0ddcfac/myapp/ clean -fdx as user@localhost
  INFO [7323847f] Finished in 0.003 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [f111f037] Running /usr/bin/env git -C /tmp/kamal-clones/myapp-e1d4eb0ddcfac/myapp/ submodule update --init as user@localhost
  INFO [f111f037] Finished in 0.016 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [64a1aab1] Running /usr/bin/env git -C /tmp/kamal-clones/myapp-e1d4eb0ddcfac/myapp/ status --porcelain as user@localhost
  INFO [64a1aab1] Finished in 0.003 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [4ebdd1dd] Running /usr/bin/env git -C /tmp/kamal-clones/myapp-e1d4eb0ddcfac/myapp/ rev-parse HEAD as user@localhost
  INFO [4ebdd1dd] Finished in 0.002 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [f739003b] Running docker buildx inspect kamal-local-docker-container as user@localhost
  INFO [f739003b] Finished in 0.129 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [2db71c0c] Running docker buildx build --push --platform linux/amd64 --builder kamal-local-docker-container -t myuser/myapp:f87ed63df53887359dc65647081ca7c0de3f52d3 -t myuser/myapp:latest --label service="myapp" --file Dockerfile . as user@localhost
 DEBUG [2db71c0c] Command: docker buildx build --push --platform linux/amd64 --builder kamal-local-docker-container -t myuser/myapp:f87ed63df53887359dc65647081ca7c0de3f52d3 -t myuser/myapp:latest --label service="myapp" --file Dockerfile .
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #0 building with "kamal-local-docker-container" instance using docker-container driver
 DEBUG [2db71c0c] 
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #1 [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #1 transferring dockerfile: 901B done
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #1 DONE 0.0s
 DEBUG [2db71c0c] 
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #2 [auth] library/ruby:pull token for registry-1.docker.io
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #2 DONE 0.0s
 DEBUG [2db71c0c] 
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #3 [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ruby:3.3.6
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #3 DONE 1.0s
 DEBUG [2db71c0c] 
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #4 [internal] load .dockerignore
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #4 transferring context: 2B done
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #4 DONE 0.0s
 DEBUG [2db71c0c] 
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #5 [ 1/14] FROM docker.io/library/ruby:3.3.6@sha256:9afef279599922a4426c91d0a2a0d0c32c15ef0f65490ae83132a683d58ab978
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #5 resolve docker.io/library/ruby:3.3.6@sha256:9afef279599922a4426c91d0a2a0d0c32c15ef0f65490ae83132a683d58ab978 0.0s done
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #5 DONE 0.0s
 DEBUG [2db71c0c] 
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #6 [internal] load build context
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #6 transferring context: 140.80kB 0.1s done
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #6 DONE 0.1s
 DEBUG [2db71c0c] 
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #7 [ 6/14] RUN wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | apt-key add -
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #7 CACHED
 DEBUG [2db71c0c] 
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #8 [ 4/14] RUN apt install lsb-base lsb-release -y
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #8 CACHED
 DEBUG [2db71c0c] 
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #9 [ 5/14] RUN sh -c 'echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt $(lsb_release -cs)-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list'
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #9 CACHED
 DEBUG [2db71c0c] 
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #10 [ 7/14] RUN apt update   && apt install -y htop                     nano                     postgresql-14                     build-essential libssl-dev zlib1g-dev libreadline-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libffi-dev software-properties-common
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #10 CACHED
 DEBUG [2db71c0c] 
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #11 [ 8/14] RUN curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_18.x | bash - &&     apt-get install -y nodejs
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #11 CACHED
 DEBUG [2db71c0c] 
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #12 [ 2/14] RUN apt update
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #12 CACHED
 DEBUG [2db71c0c] 
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #13 [ 3/14] RUN apt upgrade -y
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #13 CACHED
 DEBUG [2db71c0c] 
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #14 [ 9/14] RUN gem install pg
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #14 CACHED
 DEBUG [2db71c0c] 
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #15 [10/14] ADD . /home/app/web
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #15 DONE 0.2s
 DEBUG [2db71c0c] 
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #16 [11/14] WORKDIR /home/app/web
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #16 DONE 0.0s
 DEBUG [2db71c0c] 
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #17 [12/14] COPY package*.json ./
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #17 DONE 0.0s
 DEBUG [2db71c0c] 
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #18 [13/14] RUN npm install
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #18 1.783 
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #18 1.783 added 65 packages, and audited 66 packages in 2s
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #18 1.783 
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #18 1.783 8 packages are looking for funding
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #18 1.783   run `npm fund` for details
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #18 1.784 
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #18 1.784 found 0 vulnerabilities
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #18 1.785 npm notice
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #18 1.785 npm notice New minor version of npm available! 10.8.2 -> 10.9.1
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #18 1.785 npm notice Changelog: https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v10.9.1
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #18 1.785 npm notice To update run: npm install -g npm@10.9.1
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #18 1.785 npm notice
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #18 DONE 1.9s
 DEBUG [2db71c0c] 
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #19 [14/14] RUN bundle install --jobs 5 --retry 5
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #19 0.173 Bundler 2.5.22 is running, but your lockfile was generated with 2.5.11. Installing Bundler 2.5.11 and restarting using that version.
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #19 1.239 Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #19 1.296 Fetching bundler 2.5.11
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #19 1.395 Installing bundler 2.5.11
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #19 2.114 Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/........
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #19 64.77 Bundle complete! 27 Gemfile dependencies, 135 gems now installed.
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #19 64.77 Use `bundle info [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #19 64.77 Post-install message from websocket-client-simple:
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #19 64.77 The development of this gem has moved to https://github.com/ruby-jp/websocket-client-simple.
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #19 64.77 Post-install message from rubyzip:
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #19 64.77 RubyZip 3.0 is coming!
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #19 64.77 **********************
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #19 64.77 
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #19 64.77 The public API of some Rubyzip classes has been modernized to use named
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #19 64.77 parameters for optional arguments. Please check your usage of the
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #19 64.77 following classes:
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #19 64.77   * `Zip::File`
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #19 64.77   * `Zip::Entry`
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #19 64.77   * `Zip::InputStream`
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #19 64.77   * `Zip::OutputStream`
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #19 64.77 
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #19 64.77 Please ensure that your Gemfiles and .gemspecs are suitably restrictive
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #19 64.77 to avoid an unexpected breakage when 3.0 is released (e.g. ~> 2.3.0).
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #19 64.77 See https://github.com/rubyzip/rubyzip for details. The Changelog also
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #19 64.77 lists other enhancements and bugfixes that have been implemented since
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #19 64.77 version 2.3.0.
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #19 64.77 Post-install message from sass:
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #19 64.77 
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #19 64.77 Ruby Sass has reached end-of-life and should no longer be used.
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #19 64.77 
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #19 64.77 * If you use Sass as a command-line tool, we recommend using Dart Sass, the new
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #19 64.77   primary implementation: https://sass-lang.com/install
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #19 64.77 
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #19 64.77 * If you use Sass as a plug-in for a Ruby web framework, we recommend using the
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #19 64.77   sassc gem: https://github.com/sass/sassc-ruby#readme
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #19 64.77 
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #19 64.77 * For more details, please refer to the Sass blog:
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #19 64.77   https://sass-lang.com/blog/posts/7828841
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #19 64.77 
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #19 64.78 Post-install message from vite_ruby:
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #19 64.78 Thanks for installing Vite Ruby!
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #19 64.78 
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #19 64.78 If you upgraded the gem manually, please run:
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #19 64.78       bundle exec vite upgrade
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #19 64.78 Post-install message from webdrivers:
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #19 64.78 Webdrivers gem update options
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #19 64.78 *****************************
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #19 64.78 
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #19 64.78 Selenium itself now manages drivers by default: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/selenium_manager
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #19 64.78 * If you are using Ruby 3+ — please update to Selenium 4.11+ and stop requiring this gem
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #19 64.78 * If you are using Ruby 2.6+ and Selenium 4.0+ — this version will work for now
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #19 64.78 * If you use Ruby < 2.6 or Selenium 3, a 6.0 version of this gem with additional support is planned
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #19 64.78 
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #19 64.78 Restrict your gemfile to "webdrivers", "= 5.3.0" to stop seeing this message
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #19 DONE 64.9s
 DEBUG [2db71c0c] 
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #20 exporting to image
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #20 exporting layers
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #20 exporting layers 5.0s done
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #20 exporting manifest sha256:c6d03ef28cd44fe395fd6749546ae6af4cf815acab52bb1e6a412913d4b3b0cc done
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #20 exporting config sha256:683ae76dd7e5190ea0da365e81e410aba2ea02c4c576ec621f9ebb4c390dca1a done
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #20 exporting attestation manifest sha256:7ac7c20eaebe9ad983851fb0a1a87d2bf6b1787dfba566913f44330659b9a0f2 0.0s done
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #20 exporting manifest list sha256:e0215d0adfe3243c02bf95b96f5a3121f9c470f1f00b7198f90148019e74b63d done
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #20 pushing layers
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #20 ...
 DEBUG [2db71c0c] 
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #21 [auth] myuser/myapp:pull,push token for registry-1.docker.io
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #21 DONE 0.0s
 DEBUG [2db71c0c] 
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #20 exporting to image
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #20 pushing layers 19.9s done
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #20 pushing manifest for docker.io/myuser/myapp:f87ed63df53887359dc65647081ca7c0de3f52d3@sha256:e0215d0adfe3243c02bf95b96f5a3121f9c470f1f00b7198f90148019e74b63d
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #20 pushing manifest for docker.io/myuser/myapp:f87ed63df53887359dc65647081ca7c0de3f52d3@sha256:e0215d0adfe3243c02bf95b96f5a3121f9c470f1f00b7198f90148019e74b63d 1.4s done
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #20 pushing layers 1.4s done
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #20 pushing manifest for docker.io/myuser/myapp:latest@sha256:e0215d0adfe3243c02bf95b96f5a3121f9c470f1f00b7198f90148019e74b63d
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #20 pushing manifest for docker.io/myuser/myapp:latest@sha256:e0215d0adfe3243c02bf95b96f5a3121f9c470f1f00b7198f90148019e74b63d 0.7s done
 DEBUG [2db71c0c]       #20 DONE 28.5s
  INFO [2db71c0c] Finished in 96.831 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [1ddee41c] Running docker image rm --force myuser/myapp:f87ed63df53887359dc65647081ca7c0de3f52d3 on 111.111.111.111
  INFO [1ddee41c] Finished in 0.442 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [b3034dad] Running docker pull myuser/myapp:f87ed63df53887359dc65647081ca7c0de3f52d3 on 111.111.111.111
  INFO [b3034dad] Finished in 7.782 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [b4a1edfd] Running docker inspect -f '{{ .Config.Labels.service }}' myuser/myapp:f87ed63df53887359dc65647081ca7c0de3f52d3 | grep -x myapp || (echo "Image myuser/myapp:f87ed63df53887359dc65647081ca7c0de3f52d3 is missing the 'service' label" && exit 1) on 111.111.111.111
  INFO [b4a1edfd] Finished in 0.448 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [0937a654] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p .kamal on 111.111.111.111
  INFO [0937a654] Finished in 0.400 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
Acquiring the deploy lock...
Ensure kamal-proxy is running...
  INFO [2487d202] Running docker network create kamal on 111.111.111.111
  INFO [6ab8a3ef] Running docker login -u [REDACTED] -p [REDACTED] on 111.111.111.111
  INFO [6ab8a3ef] Finished in 0.536 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [5d9758cd] Running docker inspect kamal-proxy --format '{{.Config.Image}}' | cut -d: -f2 on 111.111.111.111
  INFO [5d9758cd] Finished in 0.423 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [49f958c0] Running docker container start kamal-proxy || docker run --name kamal-proxy --network kamal --detach --restart unless-stopped --volume kamal-proxy-config:/home/kamal-proxy/.config/kamal-proxy $(cat .kamal/proxy/options || echo "--publish 80:80 --publish 443:443 --log-opt max-size=10m") basecamp/kamal-proxy:v0.8.2 on 111.111.111.111
  INFO [49f958c0] Finished in 0.421 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
Detect stale containers...
  INFO [67b51b5f] Running docker ps --filter label=service=myapp --filter label=role=web --format "{{.Names}}" | while read line; do echo ${line#myapp-web-}; done on 111.111.111.111
  INFO [67b51b5f] Finished in 0.412 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [6ded3222] Running /usr/bin/env sh -c 'docker ps --latest --format '\''{{.Names}}'\'' --filter label=service=myapp --filter label=role=web --filter status=running --filter status=restarting --filter ancestor=$(docker image ls --filter reference=myuser/myapp:latest --format '\''{{.ID}}'\'') ; docker ps --latest --format '\''{{.Names}}'\'' --filter label=service=myapp --filter label=role=web --filter status=running --filter status=restarting' | head -1 | while read line; do echo ${line#myapp-web-}; done on 111.111.111.111
  INFO [6ded3222] Finished in 0.469 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
Start container with version f87ed63df53887359dc65647081ca7c0de3f52d3 (or reboot if already running)...
  INFO [7fca1d38] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p .kamal/apps/myapp/assets/extracted/web-f87ed63df53887359dc65647081ca7c0de3f52d3 && docker stop -t 1 myapp-web-assets 2> /dev/null || true && docker run --name myapp-web-assets --detach --rm --entrypoint sleep myuser/myapp:f87ed63df53887359dc65647081ca7c0de3f52d3 1000000 && docker cp -L myapp-web-assets:/home/app/web/public/. .kamal/apps/myapp/assets/extracted/web-f87ed63df53887359dc65647081ca7c0de3f52d3 && docker stop -t 1 myapp-web-assets on 111.111.111.111
  INFO [7fca1d38] Finished in 2.779 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [2439d7f9] Running /usr/bin/env sh -c 'docker ps --latest --format '\''{{.Names}}'\'' --filter label=service=myapp --filter label=role=web --filter status=running --filter status=restarting --filter ancestor=$(docker image ls --filter reference=myuser/myapp:latest --format '\''{{.ID}}'\'') ; docker ps --latest --format '\''{{.Names}}'\'' --filter label=service=myapp --filter label=role=web --filter status=running --filter status=restarting' | head -1 | while read line; do echo ${line#myapp-web-}; done on 111.111.111.111
  INFO [2439d7f9] Finished in 0.480 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [2ca1d653] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p .kamal/apps/myapp/assets/volumes/web-f87ed63df53887359dc65647081ca7c0de3f52d3 ; cp -rnT .kamal/apps/myapp/assets/extracted/web-f87ed63df53887359dc65647081ca7c0de3f52d3 .kamal/apps/myapp/assets/volumes/web-f87ed63df53887359dc65647081ca7c0de3f52d3 on 111.111.111.111
  INFO [2ca1d653] Finished in 0.401 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [15013101] Running docker container ls --all --filter name=^myapp-web-f87ed63df53887359dc65647081ca7c0de3f52d3$ --quiet on 111.111.111.111
  INFO [15013101] Finished in 0.425 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO Renaming container f87ed63df53887359dc65647081ca7c0de3f52d3 to f87ed63df53887359dc65647081ca7c0de3f52d3_replaced_c684b62df2bb7670 as already deployed on 111.111.111.111
  INFO [613b9213] Running docker rename myapp-web-f87ed63df53887359dc65647081ca7c0de3f52d3 myapp-web-f87ed63df53887359dc65647081ca7c0de3f52d3_replaced_c684b62df2bb7670 on 111.111.111.111
  INFO [613b9213] Finished in 0.441 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [98e18634] Running /usr/bin/env sh -c 'docker ps --latest --format '\''{{.Names}}'\'' --filter label=service=myapp --filter label=role=web --filter status=running --filter status=restarting --filter ancestor=$(docker image ls --filter reference=myuser/myapp:latest --format '\''{{.ID}}'\'') ; docker ps --latest --format '\''{{.Names}}'\'' --filter label=service=myapp --filter label=role=web --filter status=running --filter status=restarting' | head -1 | while read line; do echo ${line#myapp-web-}; done on 111.111.111.111
  INFO [98e18634] Finished in 0.482 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [c2a30d00] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p .kamal/apps/myapp/env/roles on 111.111.111.111
  INFO [c2a30d00] Finished in 0.401 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO Uploading .kamal/apps/myapp/env/roles/web.env 100.0%
  INFO [57189b3f] Running docker run --detach --restart unless-stopped --name myapp-web-f87ed63df53887359dc65647081ca7c0de3f52d3 --network kamal --hostname 111.111.111.111-91b4763f586d -e KAMAL_CONTAINER_NAME="myapp-web-f87ed63df53887359dc65647081ca7c0de3f52d3" -e KAMAL_VERSION="f87ed63df53887359dc65647081ca7c0de3f52d3" --env-file .kamal/apps/myapp/env/roles/web.env --log-opt max-size="10m" --volume $(pwd)/.kamal/apps/myapp/assets/volumes/web-f87ed63df53887359dc65647081ca7c0de3f52d3:/home/app/web/public --label service="myapp" --label role="web" --label destination myuser/myapp:f87ed63df53887359dc65647081ca7c0de3f52d3 on 111.111.111.111
  INFO [57189b3f] Finished in 1.187 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [b50ff760] Running docker container ls --all --filter name=^myapp-web-f87ed63df53887359dc65647081ca7c0de3f52d3$ --quiet on 111.111.111.111
  INFO [b50ff760] Finished in 0.452 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [4cc302b4] Running docker exec kamal-proxy kamal-proxy deploy myapp-web --target="bfd9ed608a86:3000" --host="111.111.111.111" --deploy-timeout="30s" --drain-timeout="30s" --buffer-requests --buffer-responses --log-request-header="Cache-Control" --log-request-header="Last-Modified" --log-request-header="User-Agent" on 111.111.111.111
 ERROR Failed to boot web on 111.111.111.111
  INFO First web container is unhealthy on 111.111.111.111, not booting any other roles
  INFO [5152e0d1] Running docker container ls --all --filter name=^myapp-web-f87ed63df53887359dc65647081ca7c0de3f52d3$ --quiet | xargs docker logs --timestamps 2>&1 on 111.111.111.111
  INFO [5152e0d1] Finished in 0.443 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 ERROR 2024-11-29T16:51:56.374350519Z Switch to inspect mode.
2024-11-29T16:51:56.374929062Z 
2024-11-29T16:51:57.328851234Z Switch to inspect mode.
2024-11-29T16:51:57.329316841Z 
2024-11-29T16:51:58.289470336Z Switch to inspect mode.
2024-11-29T16:51:58.290058800Z 
2024-11-29T16:51:59.412712421Z Switch to inspect mode.
2024-11-29T16:51:59.412778089Z 
2024-11-29T16:52:00.992786320Z Switch to inspect mode.
2024-11-29T16:52:00.993356175Z 
2024-11-29T16:52:03.354036340Z Switch to inspect mode.
2024-11-29T16:52:03.354696622Z 
2024-11-29T16:52:07.300035289Z Switch to inspect mode.
2024-11-29T16:52:07.300680351Z 
2024-11-29T16:52:14.440548612Z Switch to inspect mode.
2024-11-29T16:52:14.441091407Z
  INFO [dc35bb57] Running docker container ls --all --filter name=^myapp-web-f87ed63df53887359dc65647081ca7c0de3f52d3$ --quiet | xargs docker inspect --format '{{json .State.Health}}' on 111.111.111.111
  INFO [dc35bb57] Finished in 0.501 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 ERROR null
  INFO [ebdf0697] Running docker container ls --all --filter name=^myapp-web-f87ed63df53887359dc65647081ca7c0de3f52d3$ --quiet | xargs docker stop on 111.111.111.111
  INFO [ebdf0697] Finished in 0.450 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
Releasing the deploy lock...
  Finished all in 153.9 seconds
  ERROR (SSHKit::Command::Failed): Exception while executing on host 111.111.111.111: docker exit status: 1
docker stdout: Nothing written
docker stderr: Error: target failed to become healthy

i can't find a solution for that, i tried to find some similar issue on kamal repository like this one but i can't make a solution using that.
